# Stubbing request.host in Capybara 2.0 / Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

My application needs to act differently on certain request.host values. I test this behavior with Cucumber. Before Capybara 2.0 I was able to mimic the right request.host value by executing this Cucumber step:

```
Given /^the url starts with "([^"]*)"$/ do |url|
  Capybara.app_host = "http://#{url}"
end
```

But now with Capybara 2.0.1, my browser actually navigates to the set URL, instead of staying on my test server and pretending to be from that URL.

So my question is: how do I correctly "stub request.host" in Capybara 2.0?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get through not by stubbing `request.host` but setting these:

```
default_url_options[:host] = host
Capybara.app_host = "http://" + host
```

Hope that helps.